# Deploying a tomcat application with distinct environment entries and resource references

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, build, web-deployment, deployment-descriptor

I have developed a web application that runs on an Apache Tomcat 7.0.14 server locally (my development environment).  I am ready to push my application to a production host, but I am having issues managing distinct entry values for each environment.

My current build process is performed entirely within my Netbeans 7.0.1 IDE.  It uses Ant, which is something I will admit I am not familiar with, and generates a .war file.  I am able to deploy to my production host by copying this .war file.  The application runs, though it is missing all the correct production configuration data.

I have written my application to be reasonably configurable.  Like most apps, a variety of data must vary between my development environment and the production environment.  I am able to separate all this data into my deployment descriptor (web.xml) or context configuration (context.xml) file, and then read it within my application.  The details of the values are not be particularly relevant, but as an example there is at least one Resource reference value that serves as a DataSource.

What I am not able to do is to easily maintain separate values for my distinct configurations.  I'm hoping to have a second copy of the web.xml or context.xml file, which I could use to build a separate copy of a .war file to deploy to production.  I would also be happy with a solution that permits me to insert some kind of variables (${}?) into this file.  However, I must be able to maintain the data itself in a file because there will be a large number of entries.  Since the data will be in files either way, I thought the natural solution was a second web.xml or context.xml file.

Ideally, I'd like a simple solution within Netbeans.  Lacking that, instructions for doing this in Ant would probably be sufficient.  Any relevant terminology would be helpful as well.  I've gotten lost reading about "contexts", "environments", and "deployments" in tomcat, which have meanings other than what I'm looking for.  Finally, if this can not be done via either, is there a tool that could help?  Writing a distinct shell script would be far from ideal.

It's hard to believe there is not a trivial solution to this.  It seems like the sort of thing that every deployment would need to address.  Isn't that why the entries and references exist in xml?  However, I could find nothing regarding this in the Tomcat manual.

Answer (score 2):

You have lots of options. For build specific properties I would recommend creating property files for each environment and loading them via the `property` task in Ant. So for example, given hypothetical environments *dev*, *qa*, *prod*, you could have property files with names build.*{env}*.properties, and load them up like so:

*build.xml*

```
<property file="build.${environment}.properties"/>
```

invoked as:

> ant  -Denvironment=dev

That gives you some useful build time property replacement. But of course, you are more interested in replacing variables in your project files. One of the ways of doing that is with the Ant [Replace Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html). Example usage:

```
<target name="prepare-resources">
    <replace dir="${targetdir}" replacefilterfile="vars.${environment}.properties">
        <include name="**/*.txt"/>
     </replace>
</target>
```

You would invoke your Ant build's similar to the first example I gave. You can add as many resource types as you need with additional `include` directives.

And lastly, you can also choose to have a whole set of files tagged with an environment identifier, and 'promote' them to the desired build artifact using the Ant [Copy Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html). For example:

```
<target name="promote-resources">
    <copy todir="${targetdir}">
        <fileset dir="${sourcedir}"/>
        <mapper type="regexp" from="(.*).${environment}.(.*)" to="\1.\2"/>
    </copy>
</target>
```

You would fill in `targetdir` and `sourcedir` as needed. The snippet above would promote all files of the type *web.dev.xml* or *context.dev.xml* to *web.xml* and *context.xml*.

You can combine all or some of the methods above to get a highly customized build that fits your environment. I would also recommend looking at Maven as a build tool, it makes tasks like this much easier!